# Passing strings from an Activity to a DialogFragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-dialogfragment

in my activity I have this:

public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
        Button mButton;
        private Button mBtnSignUp;

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        mRelativeLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.mainView);
        mButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLogin);

        mButton.Click += mButton_Click;
        mRelativeLayout.Click += mRelativeLayout_Click;

        mBtnSignUp = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button1);
        mBtnSignUp.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
        {
                //Pull up dialog
                FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                dialog_SignUp signUpDialog = new dialog_SignUp();
                signUpDialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");

                signUpDialog.mOnSignUpComplete += signUpDialog_mOnSignUpComplete;
        };
        void signUpDialog_mOnSignUpComplete (object sender, OnSignUpEventArgs e)
        {

            Thread thread = new Thread (ActLikeARequest);
            thread.Start ();


        }
        private void ActLikeARequest()
        {

            Thread.Sleep (3000);
        }
```

And in the dialog I have:

```
public class OnSignUpEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private string mFirstName;
        private string mEmail;
        private string mPassword;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get{ return mFirstName; }
            set{ mFirstName=value;}

        }
        public string Email
        {
            get{ return mEmail; }
            set{ mEmail=value;}

        }
        public string Password
        {
            get{ return mPassword; }
            set{ mPassword=value;}

        }

        public OnSignUpEventArgs (string firstName, string email, string password) : base()
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            Email = email;
            Password = password;
        }

    }

    class dialog_SignUp:DialogFragment
    {
        private Button mBtnSignUp;
        private EditText mFirstName;
        private EditText mEmail;
        private EditText mPassword;

        public event EventHandler<OnSignUpEventArgs> mOnSignUpComplete;


        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.dialog_sign_up, container, false);

            mBtnSignUp = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnDialogEmail);
            mFirstName = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.txtFirstName);
            mEmail = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.txtEmail);
            mPassword = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.txtPassword);

            mBtnSignUp.Click += mBtnSignUp_Click;



            return view;
        }

        void mBtnSignUp_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //User has clicked the sign up button

            mOnSignUpComplete.Invoke (this, new OnSignUpEventArgs(mFirstName.Text, mEmail.Text, mPassword.Text));
            this.Dismiss ();

        }
        public override void OnActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Dialog.Window.RequestFeature (WindowFeatures.NoTitle); //Sets the title bar to invisible
            base.OnActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);
            Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_animation; //Set the animation
        }
    }
```

The question is, how can I pass data(strings) from the activity into the dialog, so that when it is called, the TextViews get the data I'm passing?

Is it something to add in the actitity,  but what?

Comment: have you stepped through the code.. also what does the class look like within the first code block that you have posted..?

Comment: @MethodMan I have already edited the first block of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you need to be able to accept a parameter in your dialog_signup.

```
class dialog_SignUp:DialogFragment
 {
    private Button mBtnSignUp;
    private EditText mFirstName;
    private EditText mEmail;
    private EditText mPassword;
    String parameter="";
    public event EventHandler<OnSignUpEventArgs> mOnSignUpComplete;

    public dialog_SignUp(String parameterIn){
       parameter=parameterIn;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.dialog_sign_up, container, false);

        mBtnSignUp = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnDialogEmail);
        mFirstName = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.txtFirstName);
        mFirstName.setText(parameter);
        mEmail = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.txtEmail);
        mPassword = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.txtPassword);

        mBtnSignUp.Click += mBtnSignUp_Click;



        return view;
    }
```

then replace `dialog_SignUp signUpDialog = new dialog_SignUp();` with `dialog_SignUp signUpDialog = new dialog_SignUp(stringToSend);`

Comment: thanks a lot :D , it worked just fine ;)  The hours I've spent searching how to do this... Thanks man

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer, a newbie so I need the rep haha. Thanks

Comment: ahah, me too, could you up my question, I'd like to be a part of the chat, so that I could interact with other users faster

Comment: That's what I wanted haha, took me ages get 100 rep so I can join an android chat ha. Thank you, ill vote your question.

Comment: This may work as expected, but it is another case of a leaky abstraction. In this case Xamarin is hiding the fact that you should not create non-default constructors in fragments, and DialogFragment is a fragment. Android Studio will issue this warning: "`Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead`". This code will probably fail if the dialog is used inside an activity as a standard fragment, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you can always use The Application class to define a variable there.

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
[Application]
public class App : Application
{
    public ParseObject currentBusiness { get; set;}

    public App (IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate ()
    {
        base.OnCreate ();

        currentBusiness = new ParseObject ("Business");
    }
}
}
```

Then you can access it from evewhere in that way:

```
App _app = (App)Application.Context;
var curentBusiness = _app.currentBusiness;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Property feature of Class.

**Dialog Fragment Code**

```
class Error : DialogFragment
{
    public string getErrorMsg { get; set; } // this gets the message


    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Error, container, false);
        TextView text = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtError);
        text.Text = getErrorMsg; //here the message is set to the TextView
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Calling Method**

```
      FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
      Error obj = new Error();
      obj.Cancelable = false;
      obj.getErrorMsg = passMyString; // in this line you send message to The Class
      obj.Show(transaction, "error");
```